# PHP Search Code from HTML form

Tags: php, mysql

I had a previous question on here a few minutes ago about a syntax error that was sorted. I need help getting this script working or at least for someone to point me in the right direction.

This is a search script to search by multiple fields. The search() array works fine and is a series of tickboxes with the following code:

```
<td width="22"><input type="checkbox" name="search[olevel = 'Yes']" id="search[olevel = 'Yes']" value="1"/>
```

The postcode box is a text box with the following code:

```
<input name="postcode[]" type="text" id="postcode[]" size="12" maxlength="12" /></td>
```

When I tick the olevel box it returns all the records that have Yes in the olevel field. That works as I expect.

If I put in anything in the postcode box it returns no results.

Here is the php code for the search engine.

```
<?php
include ('c1.php');
if ($_COOKIE["auth"] == "1") {
    $display_block = "<p>You are an authorized user.</p>";
} else {
    header("Location: userlogin.html");
    exit;
}
doDB();
$display_block = "<h1>Results</h1>";
if (isset($_POST['search']) && !empty($_POST['search'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['search'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == 1)
            $search[] = "$key";
        $searchstring = implode(' AND ', $search);
        $post_map = array(
            'postcode' => 'candididate_contact_details.postcode'
        );
    }
    if (isset($_POST['postcode']) && !empty($_POST['postcode'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['postcode'] as $key => $value) {
            if (array_key_exists($key, $post_map))
                $search[] = $post_map[$key] . '=' . mysql_real_escape_string($value);
            echo $searchstring;
            echo $search;
            $query = "SELECT candidate_id.master_id, candidate_contact_details.first_name, candidate_contact_details.last_name, candidate_contact_details.home_phone, candidate_contact_details.work_phone, candidate_contact_details.mobile_phone, candidate_contact_details.email FROM candidate_id, candidate_contact_details, qualifications, security_experience, previous_career WHERE qualifications.active = 'finished' and candidate_id.master_id = candidate_contact_details.master_id and candidate_id.master_id = qualifications.master_id and candidate_id.master_id = security_experience.master_id and candidate_id.master_id = previous_career.master_id and $searchstring";
            $query_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)
                    or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
            // $search = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
            {
                $display_block .= "
    <table width=\"98%\" cellspacing=\"2\" border=\"1\">
    <tr>
    <th>Registration Number</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Home Number</th>
    <th>Work Number</th>
    <th>Mobile Number</th>
    <th>E-Mail</th>
    </tr>";
                while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query_res)) {
                    $regnum = $result['master_id'];
                    $first_name = $result['first_name'];
                    $last_name = $result['last_name'];
                    $home_phone = $result['home_phone'];
                    $work_phone = $result['work_phone'];
                    $mobile_phone = $result['mobile_phone'];
                    $email = $result['email'];
                    $display_block .= "
    <tr>
    <td align=\"center\">$regnum <br></td>
    <td align=\"center\">$first_name <br></td>
    <td align=\"center\">$last_name <br></td>
    <td align=\"center\">$home_phone <br></td>
    <td align=\"center\">$work_phone <br></td>
    <td align=\"center\">$mobile_phone <br></td>
    <td align=\"center\">$email <br></td>
    </tr>";
                }
                $display_block .= "</table>";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title> Display results</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php echo $display_block; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know I am doing something wrong but cannot quite figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `name="search[olevel = 'Yes']"` I don't think that's a valid name, someone will have to back me up on that though.

Comment: That is the section that works at the moment. trying to figure this out since all the search example scripts I have found so far deal with either 1 field in the database or all of them.

Comment: But why do you use `search[olevel = 'Yes']`? Wouldn't just `search[1/0]` work just as well? I'm just asking because it's things like these that can sometimes break scripts behind the scenes when the parser can't figure it our properly.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, you have several postcodes per form.

then `id="postcode[]"` is wrong as there will be several id named the same in dom.

just delete that from your code.

Comment: No. Just one postcode. postcode is a text field denoting an area ie. HA2. Need to be able to searth for everyone in that postcode area with an olevel.